Expressing Joint Gaussians as an Affine Function with Added Indendependent Gaussian Noise: Why do we need the noise?
A textbook I am reading, describes the following:
Given any jointly Gaussian random vectors $X_A$ and $X_B$, $X_A$ can be expressed as an affine function of $X_B$ with added independent gaussian noise $\epsilon$.
$$X_A = AX_B+b+\epsilon$$
where $$A=\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}$$
$$b = \mu_A-\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}\mu_B$$
$$\epsilon \sim N(0, \Sigma_{A|B})$$
They further mention that this kind of representation is useful due to its compactness.
However, I am confused as to why we need to add the noise $\epsilon$. What is its significance and what happens if we do not add it?
Furthermore, I am also not quite sure how this is related to joint Gaussian random vectors. How is the above useful in computing, say $f(x_a, x_b)$, where $f$ is the joint probability density function, that we don't know?

Are some of the covariance matrices allowed to be singular? That could explain the necessity of noise

The assertion isn't true without the $\epsilon$ term, for example if $X_A$ and $X_B$ have different dimensions. Consider the case where $X_B$ is univariate and $X_A$ is bivariate: Affine functions of $X_B$ will never be able to capture all possible bivariate Gaussian distributions.
Given jointly distributed Gaussian vectors $X_A$ and $X_B$, the assertion is that you can find $A$, $b$ and a mean-zero Gaussian vector $\epsilon$ independent from $X_B$ to satisfy $$X_A=AX_B + b + \epsilon.\tag1$$ Indeed, you can derive three equations in three unknowns $A$, $b$ and $\Sigma_\epsilon$ (the covariance matrix of $\epsilon$) by: taking expectation of (1); right-multiplying (1) by $X_A^T$ and taking expectation; and right-multiplying (1) by $X_B^T$ and taking expectation. Solve these to find (assuming $\Sigma_{BB}$ is invertible) $$\begin{aligned}A&=\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1},\\b&=\mu_A-A\mu_B,\\\Sigma_\epsilon&=\Sigma_{AA}-\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}\Sigma_{BA},\end{aligned}$$ the same as you've written. This implies that when the noise term $\epsilon$ is omitted from (1), the only kinds of $X_A$ that can be generated are those for which $\Sigma_{AA}=\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}\Sigma_{BA}$.
The benefit of  representation (1) is that you can find the conditional distribution of $X_A$ given $X_B$ by inspection: Equation (1) already expresses $X_A$ as a function of $X_B$, so you can read off the fact that conditional on $X_B$, $X_A$ has Gaussian distribution with conditional mean and covariance
$$\begin{aligned}E(X_A\mid X_B)&= AX_B + b=\mu_A+\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}(X_B-\mu_B),\\ \operatorname{Var}(X_A\mid X_B) &= \Sigma_\epsilon=\Sigma_{AA}-\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}\Sigma_{BA},\end{aligned}$$ which explains  the notation $\epsilon\sim N(0,\Sigma_{A\mid B})$.
Note: This approach gives another way of deriving the conditional distribution.
